# Demonstration in arithmetic function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I need help to know (in detail) how to prove that the product of two multiplicative arithmetic functions is a multiplicative arithmetic function.

$$$$$f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are functions multiplicative, show that $$h(n)=f(n)\cdot g(n)$$is multiplicative function.

Comment: All you need to show is that if (m,n)=1, then (fg)(mn)=(fg)(m)*(fg)(n)

Comment: The ordinary product, not the convolution product? If so, it is one line.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It's the same simple product.

Comment: Then the hint given by Mike is plenty. Note that $h(mn)=f(mn)g(mn)=f(m)f(n)g(m)g(n)=h(m)h(n)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Very good, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. A complete answer has been given by Don Antonio.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the simple product it's a one liner as Andre says:

$$fg(mn):=f(mn)g(mn)=f(m)f(n)g(m)g(n)=f(m)g(m)f(n)g(n)=fg(m)\cdot fg(n)$$

Comment: Very good, thank you.
However, so that I can improve on my next questions, you know why I got a "-1" in this question?

Comment: Do you mean why your question was downvoted? I don't know, @marcelolpjunior...perhaps someone thought you didn't show any real self work in your question...?

Comment: Some people downvote homework-style questions that do not show some work. In any case, showing work is a very good idea, since it helps answerers to focus their answer on the source of difficulty.

Comment: And when you are a beginner and do not really even know where from?

Comment: Well @marcelolpjunior, we all are assuming askers here are high-school-college-university level and up, and one **must** at least understand what he's asking about. Things like "I've no the slightest idea what to do" are usually unacceptable since there are books, sites, etc. that one assumes the asker checked *first* before asking.

Comment: Sometimes happens to me. $$:($$

Comment: But then why don't you first approach your teacher/instructor, @marcelolpjunior? Whata bout checking books, sites **first** ? Then, after you've already made some progress you can write, tell us what you did and *then* ask something about a particular thing where you're stuck.

Comment: I will try to books and / or websites, because my teacher is the type that does not like teaching and does his job well done. Let's say here in Brazil things unfortunately do not work very well in some respects. Do not make a renowned University, but am passionate about mathematics. And everything you try to learn it yourself, which complicates things a bit (when it comes from a school too bad).